# Python, extend/add field to tuple

Tags: python

what it is the best way to accomplish the following, either subclassing tuple or some other trick?

```
region = ( "buffer", "region" )  
region.cmd = ( "kill", "mark" )
```

Comment: You would probably subclass, but note that `region` is a tuple, not a list.

Comment: Are you reimplementing Emacs in Python?

Comment: @jwg ha, no.  This was to generate Dragon-to-emacs (speech to text) files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply subclass `tuple` without modification and it will work. By subclassing a built-in class it gains the ability to have arbitrary properties assigned to it, like normal user-defined classes.

```
class Region(tuple):
    pass

region = Region(( "buffer", "region" ))
region.cmd = ( "kill", "mark" )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Region(tuple):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Region, self).__init__(self, *args)
        self.cmd = None


region = Region(("buffer", "region"))
region.cmd = ("kill", "mark")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking.

If you want nested data structure I'd probably use a dictionary instead of a tuple.

```
region = {
    "buffer" : ("kill", "mark"),
    "region" : ("kill", "mark")
}
```

Tuples are non mutable as well I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use a named tuple: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple